# Is there an equivalent of Toastr for PyQt?

Tags: python-3.x, dialog, pyqt5, toastr

I am working on my first PyQt project and I would like to come up with a way to provide the user with success or error messages when they complete tasks. With Javascript in the past, I used [Toastr](https://codeseven.github.io/toastr/) and I was curious if there is anything like it for Python applications. I considered using the QDialog class in PyQt, but I would rather not have separate windows as popups if possible since even modeless dialog windows would be distracting for the user.

Comment: Does the notification need to be outside the window or can it be "embedded" in it?

Comment: @musicamante I would prefer that it is separate from the window if possible

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**UPDATE**: I've updated the code, making it possible to show desktop-wise notifications (see below).

Implementing a desktop-aware toaster like widget is not impossible, but presents some issues that are platform dependent. On the other hand, a client-side one is easier.

I've created a small class that is able to show a notification based on the top level window of the current widget, with the possibility to set the message text, the icon, and if the notification is user-closable. I also added a nice opacity animation, that is common in such systems.

Its main use is based on a static method, similarly to what QMessageBox does, but it can also be implemented in a similar fashion by adding other features.

### UPDATE

I realized that making a desktop-wise notification is not *that* hard (but some care is required for cross-platform development, I'll leave that up to the programmer).
The following is the *updated* code that allows using `None` as a parent for the class, making the notification a desktop widget instead of a child widget of an existing Qt one. If you're reading this and you're not interested in such a feature, just check the editing history for the original (and slightly simpler) code.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys

class QToaster(QtWidgets.QFrame):
    closed = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(QToaster, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)

        self.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum, 
                           QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum)

        self.setStyleSheet('''
            QToaster {
                border: 1px solid black;
                border-radius: 4px; 
                background: palette(window);
            }
        ''')
        # alternatively:
        # self.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        # self.setFrameShape(self.Box)

        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(singleShot=True, timeout=self.hide)

        if self.parent():
            self.opacityEffect = QtWidgets.QGraphicsOpacityEffect(opacity=0)
            self.setGraphicsEffect(self.opacityEffect)
            self.opacityAni = QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(self.opacityEffect, b'opacity')
            # we have a parent, install an eventFilter so that when it's resized
            # the notification will be correctly moved to the right corner
            self.parent().installEventFilter(self)
        else:
            # there's no parent, use the window opacity property, assuming that
            # the window manager supports it; if it doesn't, this won'd do
            # anything (besides making the hiding a bit longer by half a second)
            self.opacityAni = QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(self, b'windowOpacity')
        self.opacityAni.setStartValue(0.)
        self.opacityAni.setEndValue(1.)
        self.opacityAni.setDuration(100)
        self.opacityAni.finished.connect(self.checkClosed)

        self.corner = QtCore.Qt.TopLeftCorner
        self.margin = 10

    def checkClosed(self):
        # if we have been fading out, we're closing the notification
        if self.opacityAni.direction() == self.opacityAni.Backward:
            self.close()

    def restore(self):
        # this is a "helper function", that can be called from mouseEnterEvent
        # and when the parent widget is resized. We will not close the
        # notification if the mouse is in or the parent is resized
        self.timer.stop()
        # also, stop the animation if it's fading out...
        self.opacityAni.stop()
        # ...and restore the opacity
        if self.parent():
            self.opacityEffect.setOpacity(1)
        else:
            self.setWindowOpacity(1)

    def hide(self):
        # start hiding
        self.opacityAni.setDirection(self.opacityAni.Backward)
        self.opacityAni.setDuration(500)
        self.opacityAni.start()

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if source == self.parent() and event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Resize:
            self.opacityAni.stop()
            parentRect = self.parent().rect()
            geo = self.geometry()
            if self.corner == QtCore.Qt.TopLeftCorner:
                geo.moveTopLeft(
                    parentRect.topLeft() + QtCore.QPoint(self.margin, self.margin))
            elif self.corner == QtCore.Qt.TopRightCorner:
                geo.moveTopRight(
                    parentRect.topRight() + QtCore.QPoint(-self.margin, self.margin))
            elif self.corner == QtCore.Qt.BottomRightCorner:
                geo.moveBottomRight(
                    parentRect.bottomRight() + QtCore.QPoint(-self.margin, -self.margin))
            else:
                geo.moveBottomLeft(
                    parentRect.bottomLeft() + QtCore.QPoint(self.margin, -self.margin))
            self.setGeometry(geo)
            self.restore()
            self.timer.start()
        return super(QToaster, self).eventFilter(source, event)

    def enterEvent(self, event):
        self.restore()

    def leaveEvent(self, event):
        self.timer.start()

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        # we don't need the notification anymore, delete it!
        self.deleteLater()

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        super(QToaster, self).resizeEvent(event)
        # if you don't set a stylesheet, you don't need any of the following!
        if not self.parent():
            # there's no parent, so we need to update the mask
            path = QtGui.QPainterPath()
            path.addRoundedRect(QtCore.QRectF(self.rect()).translated(-.5, -.5), 4, 4)
            self.setMask(QtGui.QRegion(path.toFillPolygon(QtGui.QTransform()).toPolygon()))
        else:
            self.clearMask()

    @staticmethod
    def showMessage(parent, message, 
                    icon=QtWidgets.QStyle.SP_MessageBoxInformation, 
                    corner=QtCore.Qt.TopLeftCorner, margin=10, closable=True, 
                    timeout=5000, desktop=False, parentWindow=True):

        if parent and parentWindow:
            parent = parent.window()

        if not parent or desktop:
            self = QToaster(None)
            self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() | QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint |
                QtCore.Qt.BypassWindowManagerHint)
            # This is a dirty hack!
            # parentless objects are garbage collected, so the widget will be
            # deleted as soon as the function that calls it returns, but if an
            # object is referenced to *any* other object it will not, at least
            # for PyQt (I didn't test it to a deeper level)
            self.__self = self

            currentScreen = QtWidgets.QApplication.primaryScreen()
            if parent and parent.window().geometry().size().isValid():
                # the notification is to be shown on the desktop, but there is a
                # parent that is (theoretically) visible and mapped, we'll try to
                # use its geometry as a reference to guess which desktop shows
                # most of its area; if the parent is not a top level window, use
                # that as a reference
                reference = parent.window().geometry()
            else:
                # the parent has not been mapped yet, let's use the cursor as a
                # reference for the screen
                reference = QtCore.QRect(
                    QtGui.QCursor.pos() - QtCore.QPoint(1, 1), 
                    QtCore.QSize(3, 3))
            maxArea = 0
            for screen in QtWidgets.QApplication.screens():
                intersected = screen.geometry().intersected(reference)
                area = intersected.width() * intersected.height()
                if area > maxArea:
                    maxArea = area
                    currentScreen = screen
            parentRect = currentScreen.availableGeometry()
        else:
            self = QToaster(parent)
            parentRect = parent.rect()

        self.timer.setInterval(timeout)

        # use Qt standard icon pixmaps; see:
        # https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyle.html#StandardPixmap-enum
        if isinstance(icon, QtWidgets.QStyle.StandardPixmap):
            labelIcon = QtWidgets.QLabel()
            self.layout().addWidget(labelIcon)
            icon = self.style().standardIcon(icon)
            size = self.style().pixelMetric(QtWidgets.QStyle.PM_SmallIconSize)
            labelIcon.setPixmap(icon.pixmap(size))

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(message)
        self.layout().addWidget(self.label)

        if closable:
            self.closeButton = QtWidgets.QToolButton()
            self.layout().addWidget(self.closeButton)
            closeIcon = self.style().standardIcon(
                QtWidgets.QStyle.SP_TitleBarCloseButton)
            self.closeButton.setIcon(closeIcon)
            self.closeButton.setAutoRaise(True)
            self.closeButton.clicked.connect(self.close)

        self.timer.start()

        # raise the widget and adjust its size to the minimum
        self.raise_()
        self.adjustSize()

        self.corner = corner
        self.margin = margin

        geo = self.geometry()
        # now the widget should have the correct size hints, let's move it to the
        # right place
        if corner == QtCore.Qt.TopLeftCorner:
            geo.moveTopLeft(
                parentRect.topLeft() + QtCore.QPoint(margin, margin))
        elif corner == QtCore.Qt.TopRightCorner:
            geo.moveTopRight(
                parentRect.topRight() + QtCore.QPoint(-margin, margin))
        elif corner == QtCore.Qt.BottomRightCorner:
            geo.moveBottomRight(
                parentRect.bottomRight() + QtCore.QPoint(-margin, -margin))
        else:
            geo.moveBottomLeft(
                parentRect.bottomLeft() + QtCore.QPoint(margin, -margin))

        self.setGeometry(geo)
        self.show()
        self.opacityAni.start()


class W(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self)
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)

        toasterLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addLayout(toasterLayout)

        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit('Ciao!')
        toasterLayout.addWidget(self.textEdit)

        self.cornerCombo = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        toasterLayout.addWidget(self.cornerCombo)
        for pos in ('TopLeft', 'TopRight', 'BottomRight', 'BottomLeft'):
            corner = getattr(QtCore.Qt, '{}Corner'.format(pos))
            self.cornerCombo.addItem(pos, corner)

        self.windowBtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Show window toaster')
        toasterLayout.addWidget(self.windowBtn)
        self.windowBtn.clicked.connect(self.showToaster)

        self.screenBtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Show desktop toaster')
        toasterLayout.addWidget(self.screenBtn)
        self.screenBtn.clicked.connect(self.showToaster)

        # a random widget for the window
        layout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QTableView())

    def showToaster(self):
        if self.sender() == self.windowBtn:
            parent = self
            desktop = False
        else:
            parent = None
            desktop = True
        corner = QtCore.Qt.Corner(self.cornerCombo.currentData())
        QToaster.showMessage(
            parent, self.textEdit.text(), corner=corner, desktop=desktop)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = W()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: This is what I was thinking of. The opacity animation is a nice touch!

Comment: @NickS I've updated the answer adding support for desktop notifications. I only tested it under my Linux environment, so it's *possible* that it might not behave as expected under Windows or MacOS. Let me know if you face any unexpected behavior.

Comment: I have it running as expected, thanks for your help!

Comment: I ran this code, and its surprisingly amazing; however, the desktop notification is, for some reason, not working on Win 10

Comment: @ThePyGuy unfortunately I don't have a Windows 10 machine, so I cannot help you a lot. With "not working" are you referring to the desktop notification, right? Do you get any error message in the output?

Comment: @musicamante, yeah the desktop toaster doesn't work; however window toaster works absolutely fine. And there is no error message, it just crashes, showing *Python has stopped Working* windows dialog.

Comment: Now it works absolutely fine. `QtGui` was not imported and that's why the application was crashing. I expect it to throw `NameError`, but there was no error. Later I noticed error pointed by the IDE.

Comment: Exceptional work, worked great for me.

Answer (score 6):

Try it:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import (QRectF, Qt, QPropertyAnimation, pyqtProperty, 
                          QPoint, QParallelAnimationGroup, QEasingCurve)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QPainterPath, QColor, QPen
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QLabel, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QApplication,
                             QLineEdit, QPushButton)


class BubbleLabel(QWidget):

    BackgroundColor = QColor(195, 195, 195)
    BorderColor = QColor(150, 150, 150)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        text = kwargs.pop("text", "")
        super(BubbleLabel, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setWindowFlags(
            Qt.Window | Qt.Tool | Qt.FramelessWindowHint | 
            Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint | Qt.X11BypassWindowManagerHint)
        # Set minimum width and height
        self.setMinimumWidth(200)
        self.setMinimumHeight(58)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        # Top left and bottom right margins (16 below because triangles are included)
        layout.setContentsMargins(8, 8, 8, 16)
        self.label = QLabel(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.setText(text)
        # Get screen height and width
        self._desktop = QApplication.instance().desktop()

    def setText(self, text):
        self.label.setText(text)

    def text(self):
        return self.label.text()

    def stop(self):
        self.hide()
        self.animationGroup.stop()
        self.close()

    def show(self):
        super(BubbleLabel, self).show()
        # Window start position
        startPos = QPoint(
            self._desktop.screenGeometry().width() - self.width() - 100,
            self._desktop.availableGeometry().height() - self.height())
        endPos = QPoint(
            self._desktop.screenGeometry().width() - self.width() - 100,
            self._desktop.availableGeometry().height() - self.height() * 3 - 5)
        self.move(startPos)
        # Initialization animation
        self.initAnimation(startPos, endPos)

    def initAnimation(self, startPos, endPos):
        # Transparency animation
        opacityAnimation = QPropertyAnimation(self, b"opacity")
        opacityAnimation.setStartValue(1.0)
        opacityAnimation.setEndValue(0.0)
        # Set the animation curve
        opacityAnimation.setEasingCurve(QEasingCurve.InQuad)
        opacityAnimation.setDuration(4000)  
        # Moving up animation
        moveAnimation = QPropertyAnimation(self, b"pos")
        moveAnimation.setStartValue(startPos)
        moveAnimation.setEndValue(endPos)
        moveAnimation.setEasingCurve(QEasingCurve.InQuad)
        moveAnimation.setDuration(5000)  
        # Parallel animation group (the purpose is to make the two animations above simultaneously)
        self.animationGroup = QParallelAnimationGroup(self)
        self.animationGroup.addAnimation(opacityAnimation)
        self.animationGroup.addAnimation(moveAnimation)
        # Close window at the end of the animation
        self.animationGroup.finished.connect(self.close)  
        self.animationGroup.start()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        super(BubbleLabel, self).paintEvent(event)
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)  # Antialiasing

        rectPath = QPainterPath()                     # Rounded Rectangle
        triPath = QPainterPath()                      # Bottom triangle

        height = self.height() - 8                    # Offset up 8
        rectPath.addRoundedRect(QRectF(0, 0, self.width(), height), 5, 5)
        x = self.width() / 5 * 4
        triPath.moveTo(x, height)                     # Move to the bottom horizontal line 4/5
        # Draw triangle
        triPath.lineTo(x + 6, height + 8)
        triPath.lineTo(x + 12, height)

        rectPath.addPath(triPath)                     # Add a triangle to the previous rectangle

        # Border brush
        painter.setPen(QPen(self.BorderColor, 1, Qt.SolidLine,
                            Qt.RoundCap, Qt.RoundJoin))
        # Background brush
        painter.setBrush(self.BackgroundColor)
        # Draw shape
        painter.drawPath(rectPath)
        # Draw a line on the bottom of the triangle to ensure the same color as the background
        painter.setPen(QPen(self.BackgroundColor, 1,
                            Qt.SolidLine, Qt.RoundCap, Qt.RoundJoin))
        painter.drawLine(x, height, x + 12, height)

    def windowOpacity(self):
        return super(BubbleLabel, self).windowOpacity()

    def setWindowOpacity(self, opacity):
        super(BubbleLabel, self).setWindowOpacity(opacity)

    # Since the opacity property is not in QWidget, you need to redefine one
    opacity = pyqtProperty(float, windowOpacity, setWindowOpacity)


class TestWidget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TestWidget, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.msgEdit = QLineEdit(self, returnPressed=self.onMsgShow)
        self.msgButton = QPushButton("Display content", self, clicked=self.onMsgShow)
        layout.addWidget(self.msgEdit)
        layout.addWidget(self.msgButton)

    def onMsgShow(self):
        msg = self.msgEdit.text().strip()
        if not msg:
            return
        if hasattr(self, "_blabel"):
            self._blabel.stop()
            self._blabel.deleteLater()
            del self._blabel
        self._blabel = BubbleLabel()
        self._blabel.setText(msg)
        self._blabel.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = TestWidget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Wow! This is nicely implemented.

Comment: Great work! really helping and very nicely designed

Comment: This code has some deprecated use of functions, I have edited and uploaded as a gist https://gist.github.com/Tuhin-thinks/d94c613ba0f75df0c8104c067970fc92

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing like that even in Qt 6.

Anyways, you said "but I would rather not have separate windows as popups if possible since even modeless dialog windows would be distracting for the user.".

Yes, there are two things necessary for the toast, and there is a solution.

1. Should not be a separated window - Qt.SubWindow

   self.setWindowFlags(Qt.SubWindow)
2. Should ignore the mouse event, be unable to focus - Qt.WA_TransparentForMouseEvents

   self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TransparentForMouseEvents, True)

Based on those rules, i made the toast that user can set the text, font, color(text or background) of it.

Here is my repo if you want to check the detail: https://github.com/yjg30737/pyqt-toast